# node.js - starting a cmd with an infinitely running process

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd, spawn

i have following code on node for windows:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    out = fs.openSync('./out.log', 'a'),
    err = fs.openSync('./out.log', 'a');

spawn('cmd', [ '/c', 'start', '""', __dirname + tstDir  +  'bin/test.bat', 'agent', ' -f ', configuration.path2lgst + 'test.conf' ], {
   stdio: [ 'ignore', out, err ], // piping stdout and stderr to out.log
   detached: true
}).unref();
```

In general i want to start a cmd which executes a .bat file that runs a process infinetly. node.js should return after this is initiated.

The problem is that what ever i try, either the cmd exits when node finished starting the cmd with the batch file or everything starts fine (like above code) but the process in node.js never returns.

Any ideas what could be done??

Cheers

Thorsten

Comment: If it was Linux just use `nohup` or `&`, and it will run the command in background but, for Windows I saw an alternative `start` you can investigate more if it is suiting you!

Comment: For Linux i knew that already. With `start` i testet already, but that is not working properly as described above. perhaps i am still missing something.